# WhereIn with dynamic property

Tags: c#, linq

I want to build `LINQ` which will be later translated to the `WHERE IN` in `sql`. In regular use case I would do:

(`querable` is `IQuerable<T>` and `arr` is `IEnumerable<int>`)

```
querable = querable.Where(e => arr.Contains(e.Id));
```

**BUT**

my issue is that the value I want to filter (`e.Id`) is dynamic, and I get it as a string. How can I do that?

*Some more background*:
I'm doing REST API endpoint in which user can send by which column he wants to filter values, so examples would be:

1. `filter: {"id": [1,2]}`

Which I want to translate into something like `queryable.Where(e => new [] {1,2}.Contains(e.Id))`

2. `filter: {"customerId": [4,5]}`

Which I want to translate into something like `queryable.Where(e => new [] {4,5}.Contains(e.CustomerId))`

So basically my input is a column name which is a `string` and list of ids which is `IEnumerable<int>`

I feel it can be achieved by using `Expression` (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40572006))  but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30173701/861716) is what you're looking for, but then using a parametrized property name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions {
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereIn<TEntity, TValue>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, string property, IEnumerable<TValue> values) {
        // x
        var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
        // x.Property            
        var prop = Expression.Property(arg, property);
        // values.Contains(x.Property)
        var contains = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Enumerable),
            "Contains",
            new[] { typeof(TValue) },
            Expression.Constant(values),
            prop
        );
        // x => values.Contains(x.Property)
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(contains, arg);
        return query.Where(lambda);
    }
}
```

Note that type of values in enumerable you pass, and property type should match for this to work (so if property is of type int - pass array of ints).

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot